# Rails 検索機能　他モデル

Tags: ruby-on-rails

マルチポストです
[参考](https://teratail.com/questions/302481)
検索機能でアソシエーションを組んでいる他モデルの情報を検索対象にしたいと思っています

####やりたいこと
検索欄にschoolsテーブルのnameカラムの値を検索すると、それに紐づくツイートを検索結果に表示させたい

例 A高校と検索するとid１のtweetが表示させる

####テーブル関係
tweetsテーブル
|id|text|school_a_id|school_b_id
|1 |おはよう|1|2|

categoriesテーブル
|id|name|
|1|A高校|
|2|B高校

**検索機能**

tweet.rb

```
class Tweet < ApplicationRecord

  def self.search(search)
    self.joins(:categories).where('text LIKE(?) OR category.name LIKE(?)',"%#{search}%","%#{search}%")
  end

  validates :title_info,length: {maximum: 30}
  validates :tournament_id,:school_a,:school_b,:school_a_score,:school_b_score,:text,:title_info ,presence: true
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :category
  has_many :comments
  has_many :likes,dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liked_users,through: :likes,source: :user
  has_many :notifications,dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :school_a,class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'school_a_id'
  belongs_to :school_b,class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'school_b_id'
  belongs_to :tournament,class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'tournament_id'
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tweets
  has_many :analyses
  has_many :forecasts
  has_ancestry
  has_many :school_a_tweets,class_name: 'Tweet',  foreign_key: 'school_a_id'
  has_many :school_b_tweets,class_name: 'Tweet',  foreign_key: 'school_b_id'
  has_many :tournament_tweets,class_name: 'Tweet',  foreign_key: 'tournament_id'
  has_many :school_analyses,class_name: 'Analysis',  foreign_key: 'school_id'
  has_many :tournament_analyses,class_name: 'Analysis',  foreign_key: 'tournament_id'
  has_many :win_school_forecasts,class_name: 'Forecast',  foreign_key: 'win_school_id'
  has_many :lose_school_forecasts,class_name: 'Forecast',  foreign_key: 'lose_school_id'
  has_many :tournament_forecasts,class_name: 'Forecast',  foreign_key: 'tournament_id'
end
```

schema

```
  create_table "categories", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "ancestry"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "tweets", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title_info"
    t.text "text"
    t.text "image"
    t.integer "school_a_score"
    t.integer "school_b_score"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.bigint "school_a_id", null: false
    t.bigint "school_b_id", null: false
    t.bigint "tournament_id", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["school_a_id"], name: "index_tweets_on_school_a_id"
    t.index ["school_b_id"], name: "index_tweets_on_school_b_id"
    t.index ["tournament_id"], name: "index_tweets_on_tournament_id"
  end
```

**エラー**

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'categories.tweet_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `tweets`.* FROM `tweets` INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`tweet_id` = `tweets`.`id` WHERE (categories.name LIKE('%A高校%') OR text LIKE('%A高校%'))
```

**推測**
エラー内容から、categoriesテーブルにtweetテーブルと紐づくIDがないからだと思っていますが、仕様上categoriesテーブルにtweet_idなどのカラムを増やすことはできません
アソシエーションの問題だと思いますが、tweet.rbのコードを変えるだけで実装する方法はないのでしょうか？

Comment: 「検索欄にschoolsテーブルのnameカラム」と質問にありますが、schoolsテーブルの説明が無いように思います。
仕様が制約しているのであれば、仕様がどのようなもので、それが何をどう制約するのかを説明すべきだと思います。そうした事を質問に追加して下さい。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。schoolsテーブルではなくcategoriesテーブルでした

Comment: schoolsテーブルとcategoriesテーブルのidをtweet_idに変更すれば、とりあえず二つのテーブルの項目間の関連付けは可能でしょう。
しかし、schoolsテーブルの項目と、categoriesテーブルの項目は１対１対応するものなのでしょうか？

tweetsテーブルは、「|id|text|school_a_id|school_b_id」というレコードから構成されています。school_a_idとschool_b_idが、それぞれ特定の高校のidなのだとしたら、tweetsテーブルのレコードとschoolsテーブルのレコードは1:他(1..2)の関係になってしまいます。

この辺りの事をふまえて、テーブルの仕様を再確認したほうが良いと思います。今のままでは、テーブル間の関係が破綻していますから。